# Create a tree structure in linq with a single list source with parent - child as strings of an object

Tags: c#, linq, razor, 2sxc

I start with a list Cats with this data:

```
Name______________ Parent__________Description_______________FilesCoded________CodingReferences

"Blue"____________ "1.Colors"______"whatever"________________10________________11

"Red"_____________ "1.Colors"______"this"____________________2_________________3

"LightBlue"_______ "Blue"__________"that"____________________3_________________4

"Square"__________ "3.Forms"_______""________________________3_________________6

"ClearBlue"_______ "LightBlue"_____""________________________0_________________0
```

I need to create this output:

```
1.Colors

____Blue

________LightBlue

____________ClearBlue

3.Forms

____Square
```

I use this code, which does the trick, but I have around 15 to 20 levels on the tree, which makes the code ugly and highly inefficient. Is there a way to make this:

1. Simpler, with a function looping through the levels instead of copying the code each time;
2. Faster. The table is quite large, so this is getting slower each level added.

Current Code:

```
@{
    var Cats = AsList(App.Data["Categories"]).OrderBy(o => o.Parent).ThenBy(oo => oo.Name);
    // List of objects with: Name, Parent, Description, and other fields.
    var FirstLevelTree = Cats.Where(a => Char.IsNumber(a.Name[0])).Select(s => s.Name).Distinct();
}

@functions{
    public CategoryInfo setCatInfo (string catName)
    {
        var Cats = AsList(App.Data["Categories"]);
        
        var returnInfo = new CategoryInfo();
        returnInfo.desc = "Error: empty string";
        returnInfo.info = "Error: empty string";
        
        var checkCat = Cats.Where(n => n.Name == catName);
        if (checkCat.Count() != 1)
        {
            returnInfo.info = "Error: no such cat in list";
            returnInfo.desc = "Error: no such cat in list";
        } else {
            var thisCat = checkCat.First();
            returnInfo.info = thisCat.Name + "somethingelse";
            returnInfo.desc = thisCat.Description + "alsosomethingelse";
        }
        return returnInfo;
    }
    
    public class CategoryInfo {
        public string info {get;set;}
        public string desc {get;set;}
    }
}

<div id="myCats">

    @foreach(var top in FirstLevelTree)
    {
        <p>@top</p>
        var setlvlOne = Cats.Where(a => a.Parent == top);
        foreach(var lvlOne in setlvlOne)
        {
            var getLvlOneInfo = setCatInfo(lvlOne.Name);
            <p style="margin-left: 20px;">@Html.Raw(getLvlOneInfo.info)</p>
               if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(getLvlOneInfo.desc))
               {
                    <p style="margin-left: 30px;">@Html.Raw(getLvlOneInfo.desc)</p>
               }
            var setlvlTwo = Cats.Where(b => b.Parent == lvlOne.Name);
            foreach(var lvlTwo in setlvlTwo)
            {
                var getLvlTwoInfo = setCatInfo(lvlTwo.Name);
                <p style="margin-left: 40px;">@Html.Raw(getLvlTwoInfo.info)</p>
                   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(getLvlTwoInfo.desc))
                   {
                        <p style="margin-left: 50px;">@Html.Raw(getLvlTwoInfo.desc)</p>
                   }
                var setlvlThree = Cats.Where(c => c.Parent == lvlTwo.Name);
                foreach(var lvlThree in setlvlThree)
                {
                    var getLvlThreeInfo = setCatInfo(lvlThree.Name);
                    <p style="margin-left: 60px;">@Html.Raw(getLvlThreeInfo.info)</p>
                       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(getLvlThreeInfo.desc))
                       {
                            <p style="margin-left: 70px;">@Html.Raw(getLvlThreeInfo.desc)</p>
                       }
                    var setlvlFour = Cats.Where(d => d.Parent == lvlThree.Name);
                    foreach(var lvlFour in setlvlFour)
                    {
                        var getLvlFourInfo = setCatInfo(lvlFour.Name);
                         <p style="margin-left: 80px;">@Html.Raw(getLvlFourInfo.info)</p>
                           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(getLvlFourInfo.desc))
                           {
                                <p style="margin-left: 90px;">@Html.Raw(getLvlFourInfo.desc)</p>
                           }
                        var setlvlFive = Cats.Where(e => e.Parent == lvlFour.Name);
                        foreach(var lvlFive in setlvlFive)
                        {
                            var getLvlFiveInfo = setCatInfo(lvlFive.Name);
                            <p style="margin-left: 100px;">@Html.Raw(getLvlFiveInfo.info)</p>
                               if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(getLvlFiveInfo.desc))
                               {
                                    <p style="margin-left: 110px;">@Html.Raw(getLvlFiveInfo.desc)</p>
                               }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }  
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Create a [Razor Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site) that calls itself recursively.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior care to post an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Simpler

Yes. Create a [Razor Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site) that calls itself recursively. That should allow you to avoid all the duplicative code in your example, and it'll support a basically infinite maximum depth without requiring any more code changes.

> Faster

It depends on what's taking all the time.

As you get more levels, presumably you're just generating a lot more HTML. That'll take more time server-side, and it'll also bog down the browser. To avoid that kind of problem, you may need to look at only loading in the parts that the user is actually interested in. For example, you can create a collapsed structure that only loads in data from deeper nodes as users drill down into it.

I'd also pay close attention to what may be happening in the code you haven't provided.

- Is `setCatInfo` an expensive operation?
- What is backing the `Cats` collection? If it's using deferred execution, like an Entity Framework DbSet, you may be doing a separate round-trip each time you iterate over the results of a `Cats.Where(...)` call.

Either way, executing `Cats.Where()` all over the place is giving your page generation an `O(n²)` algorithmic complexity. I'd suggest collecting all the categories into a lookup, grouped by their Parent:

```
var catsByParent = Cats.ToLookup(c => c.Parent);
```

This is a one-time `O(log n)` operation, and ever after that point you should be able to get the categories with a given parent much more quickly.

```
var thisLevel = catsByParent[parentLevel.Name];
```

## Side notes

- Using `@Html.Raw()` is a big code smell. Most likely you just want `@thisLevel.desc`. If `@thisLevel.desc` is guaranteed to be safe for injecting directly into your HTML, it should be an `IHtmlString`.
- Rather than putting all the HTML elements at the same level and using styling to nest them, consider using a nested HTML structure and a common CSS rule that makes each layer of that nested structure get indented a little bit from the previous one.

Comment: Creating the recursion is pretty much what I don't know how to do. The rest I'll give it a go. I'll get back with the good news if it improves the load time.

Comment: If you can figure out what specific aspect of the recursion you're struggling with, you could probably create a new question to help with that. But I think you can figure it out.

Comment: I'm getting the hang of it. Posted the current code as a new answer. Any further recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

```
@inherits ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.RazorComponent

@{
    var Cats = AsList(App.Data["Categories"]).OrderBy(o => o.Parent).ThenBy(oo => oo.Name);
    // List of objects with: Parent, Name, Description, FilesCoded, CodingReferences
    var CatsGrouped = Cats.ToLookup(a => a.Parent);
    var FirstLevelTree = Cats.Where(a => Char.IsNumber(a.Name[0])).Select(s => s.Name).Distinct();
}

<style>
.setmargins{
    padding-left: 2em;
}
</style>

@helper getChildren(string CatName, dynamic CatsGrouped)
{    
    var setChilds = CatsGrouped[CatName];
    <div class="setmargins">
    @foreach(var child in setChilds)
    {
        <div class="toogle">
            @child.Name (a: @child.FilesCoded urs: @child.CodingReferences)
            <div class="toogletarget setmargins">@(new HtmlString(child.Description))</div>
        </div>
        @getChildren(child.Name, CatsGrouped)
    }
    </div>
}

<div id="myCats" @Edit.TagToolbar(Content)>
    @foreach(var top in FirstLevelTree)
    {
        <div>@top</div>
        @getChildren(top, CatsGrouped)
    }
</div>

<script>
    $( ".toogletarget" ).toggle();
    $( ".toogle" ).click(function() {
        $(this).find('.toogletarget').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Good job figuring out the recursion. This is looking much better.  Suggestions: The task of getting the `CatsGrouped` should happen _outside_ of the helper (you can pass it as an argument to `getChildren`) to avoid that extra work. And `@(new HtmlString(...))` is no better than `Html.Raw(...)`: what happens if someone puts `<script>alert('you been haxxored');</script>` in their category description?

Comment: Updated again. The "dynamic" thing I'll update later. It's related to the content manager. The only HTML tag I need to parse is <br>, but I still need it to run...

Comment: I'd recommend you reconsider allowing people to enter `<br>`. You could do something like `<pre>` formatting to make the output respect line breaks entered by users, instead of expecting users to add HTML to their input.

Comment: If all you needs is new-line, you could also use a text field and then use RazorBlades `Tags.Nl2Br(...)` function - https://razor-blade.net/api/ToSic.Razor.Blade.Tags.html#ToSic_Razor_Blade_Tags_Nl2Br_System_String_